# jQuery Ajax request is executed too often

Tags: jquery, ajax, live

I bind via live operator a click function to a li-element:

```
$(".UListView li input.iconbutton.click").live("click", function(e){

e.preventDefault();
[...]
$.get("ajax/categorylist.php?appendcategories=true&parentcat="+currentid+"&side="+side, function(data){
[...]
});

});
```

In nearly 90% of the cases it is executed one time and everything is alright. But sometimes the ajax request is executed 2 or even more times:

This is the output from firebug: (Executed two times)

```
jquery.min.js (Zeile 4)
GET htt-p://localhost/request.php?....    200 OK     11ms   
jquery.min.js (Zeile 4)
GET htt-p://localhost/request.php?....    200 OK      19ms
```

This totaly breaks my layout, because all the elements are added in the worst case 6x to the DOM.

Does anybody know what is the reason for this behaviour? Or good idea to fix the "adding to DOM" code is executed multiple times.

Comment: I've noticed IE will sometimes do this and is either related to your event being registered twice or if you have some jquery files loaded twice - such as unobtrusive. From the console, look at the events being hooked up like so: `$("#myItem").data('events')`

Comment: Damn I did not saw the regularity. After closing the color box the click events werent destroyed. I dont know why it sometimes even happens when opening the colorbox for the first time but  putting all your comments togehter solves it! Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add `e.stopPropagation();` to your code as well as `return false;` before the end of click event

Comment: Thank you, now it works better, but not solves the problem completely. I forget to say: This quirk only appears when the ajax request is submitted within a colorbox. And when it is executed twice, all the following request within the colorbox are also executed twice until I close the colorbox and refresh the page.

Comment: Could you please provide a jsfiddler?

Answer (score 0):

I hope you are not binding the live event twice..in that case use this..

```
 $(".UListView li input.iconbutton.click").die("click");
   $(".UListView li input.iconbutton.click").live("click", function(e){
..
..
..
});
```

or sometimes even if we click a button once ,event is fired twice..

in that case after button click hide the button first to prevent multiple submit..

```
$(".UListView li input.iconbutton.click").live("click", function(e){

$(".UListView li input.iconbutton.click").hide();
..
..
..
});
```